# Why is List.sort method striked through?

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a map of errors and the number of their occurrences in some situation. I want to have a list, which contains that information in order of descending number of errors (i. e. the most frequent error is first element, the second-most - the second etc.).

I wrote following code:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(errors.entrySet());
entryList.sort{a, b -> b.value <=> a.value}
```

It works fine, but the `sort` is striked through (in Eclipse IDE with the Groovy plugin).

[image]

Why? Is that method deperecated? If so, what is the correct way to sort a list in Groovy?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098651/groovy-deprecated-methods-and-eclipse-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the Iterable version of sort instead

Because of deprecation - have a look at the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#sort(Collection%3CT%3E)). Some of `sort` methods are deprecated in favor of others.