# Groovy String.toURL is deprecated - why and what should we use instead?

Tags: groovy

In current groovy versions, the method `DefaultGroovyMethods.toURL(String)` is marked as deprecated, but without any explanation.

Why is it deprecated and what should we use instead?
I wanted to use it to easily get a file from HTTP like this:

```
def xml = "http://url.to/file.xml".toURL().text
```

Comment: is this eclipse?  then have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26098651/groovy-deprecated-methods-and-eclipse-sort

Comment: It is actually Intellij, but it seems to be exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toURL()` invoked on `String` comes from [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.html) class, not from `DefaultGroovyMethods`, so everything works fine and correct method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box,

```
new URL('xyz.com').text
```

as `java.net.URL` is automatically imported.